# Rotation issue. 2.83

Tags: modeling, object-mode, origin

I used to be able to rotate upon the origin of any given item that I was working on, but now blender just wants to rotate around the cursor, which i usual have at the world origin. This is a little annoying!! Any ideas or am i missing something? I have searched the web and not had any joy. Tried the full stop, still the rotation is of.

Comment: 10/10, it is as often the case. Just so simple, thanks so much, my life will be a little easier now..

Answer (score 1):

In 2.8 and beyond, you have a drop-down in middle (top or bottom) of the 3d-viewport where you can select the [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html).   You probably have it set (defaulted?) to "3d-cursor".  Change it to "Individual origins".

[image]

Comment: Pivot point was implemented in Blender long before 2.8+. Not only 2.7x, 2.4x had it.